# What is the benefit of using a technique with low duty cycle?

Tags: wireless

there are some techniques used into Wireless network on chip, Ultra Wide Band Interconnect is one, I have to ask the benefit of low duty cycle pulse?

I think the target of communication is to maximise the duty cycle not to minimise!!!!

But, in some papers, i found that: Ultra-Wideband interconnect (UWB-I) has the unique features of high bandwidth and low-duty cycle pulse, which make it an attractive solution for high data rate multi-processor. Any explanation pls?

Comment: UWB-I is for connecting chips instead of pins and wires. You should ask the question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Low duty cycle means lower power consumption and heat generation.